# Error-handling - 404 for remoteMethods

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have been able to easily set up a basic node.js api with the help of [strongloop](https://strongloop.com/). I have been able to add custom routes using `remoteMethods`. However, I am a bit confused in setting up `404` for those routes. I have one route for model `category` named `mature` that takes one argument(`categorId`) and fetches all games under that category that have boolean value set to true for `mature`. The endpoint url is: `http://localhost:3000/api/Categories/1004/games/mature`. If I place a non existent `categorId`, it breaks. What would be the best way to setup routes to handle `404` for errors? For example, display `"no such category id"`. [Github REPO](https://github.com/J0N47H4N/games-strongloop-api)

> common/models/category.js

```
Category.mature = function(id, limit) {
    var app = this.app;
    var Games = app.models.Games;
    Category.findById(id, {}, function(err, category){
        if (err) return callback(err);
        //set limit
        if (limit && limit > 5){
          limit = 5;
        }else if(limit === undefined){
          limit = 5;
        }
        Games.find({
            "where": {
                categoryId: id,
                mature: true,
                gameId: {gt: hashids.decode(after)}
            },
            "limit": limit
        }, function(err, gameArray) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            callback(null, gameArr);
        });
    )};
    Category.remoteMethod(
    'mature', {
        accepts: [
            {arg: 'id', type: 'number', required: true},
            {arg: 'limit',type: 'number',required: false}
        ],
        // mixing ':id' into the rest url allows $owner to be determined and used for access control
        http: {
            path: '/:id/games/mature',
            verb: 'get'
        },
        returns: {
            root: true,
            type: 'object'
        }
    }
);

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `err.statusCode` to 404 before you call `callback(err)`:

```
if(!category) {
  var err = new Error('Category ID ' + id + ' does not exist.');
  err.statusCode = 404;
  callback(err);
}
```

This will result in:

[image]

Comment: Great, What about an error code for `before=gameId` or `after=gameId`? If `gameId` doesnt exist. I tried doing something similar `if(!gameId)...` but is not working.

Comment: You're not passing the variable gameId into the Category.mature function, you're passing before and after, so you would presumably check for `if(!before || !after){}`. But then that brings you to a conundrum, maybe there isn't a before or next. What if you're on the first and last gameIds? So they are allowed to be null. What about just returning a 404 if the gamesArray is empty?

Comment: The issue here is since you are always returning cursors instead of passing in just offset and limit, you will need to add a second query to make sure there *is* a next and a before ID available. You could do some sort of count (but gameIds would need to be sequential and not skip), or simply query for the lowest and highest gameIds, then add logic to not include previous/next when the query goes outside those bounds. Or a third option is to always return *all* games and then manage your position with before and after vars and games[0].game_id-1 and games[N].game_id+1, checking that they exist

Comment: I agree with @Brain you should pass some `offset` and `limit` params instead of passing cursors. It makes no sense for pagination and you will make it more complex.